# How to get json response from the Internet on Android App

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a json response from api call.But some errors has occurred.
Please tell me what is wrong with my code...My code is like this.

```
private JSONObject responseJson;

private void apiRequest() {
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    String mRequestUrl = "http://hogehoge";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonOR = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, mRequestUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if (response.getJSONObject("response").has("error")) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException(msg);
                }else{
                    responseJson = response;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                }
            });

    jsonOR.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    mQueue.add(jsonOR);
}
```

and error messages are this.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.mymaterialapp/com.example.user.mymaterialapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
```

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.user.mymaterialapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

Comment: wats the code at `MainActivity.java:75`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you do realize the error is nowhere near the code you posted, right?

Comment: Add a null pointer check at line 75 of MainActivity.java class

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public String callWebService(String serviceURL) {
            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("");
            HttpClient client;
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {

                HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(serviceURL);
                final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
                client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                        .getContent()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    buff.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return buff.toString();
        }
```

It will return JSON

Answer (score 0):

To call a web service

```
public static String handleJsonPOSTRequest(String serverURL, String data)
        {
            int responseCode;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String serverResponseMsg = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            URL url = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            try
            {

                url = new URL(serverURL);
                Log.e("URL: ", serverURL);
                Log.e("REQUEST: ", data);
                conn = url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(POST_METHOD);
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(AppConstant.TIME_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(AppConstant.TIME_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter ouStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                ouStreamWriter.write(data);
                ouStreamWriter.flush();
                ouStreamWriter.close();

                responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == 200)
                {
                    inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    serverResponseMsg = readInputStream(inputStream);
                }

                if (serverResponseMsg != null)
                {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE: " + serverURL, serverResponseMsg);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE: " + serverURL, "Null");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }

            return serverResponseMsg;
        }
```

To get JSON from inputstream

```
private static String readInputStream(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String subMessage = null;
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader inStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inStreamReader);

            while ((subMessage = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(subMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```